# Calling stored procedure values into the console application C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, stored-procedures, console-application, readline

I have a stored procedure that its been called by a console application in C#. The stored procedure has some required parameters to be executed.
What I am trying to achieve its to be able to enter one of the required parameters into the console once the console is executed.

Something like having a text into the console asking to enter the project name and then hit on enter.

Here's my code:

```
try
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test"].ConnectionString))
    {
        string outCsvFile = @"D:\\test\\test.csv";

        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlCmd.Connection = conn;
        sqlCmd.CommandText = "projects";
        //Adding values to the stored procedure
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectTitle", "Test Project 1"); //this value I would like to add it when the console application is executed when I will hit on enter.
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", "");

        conn.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(outCsvFile)) 
            {
                file.WriteLine(reader.GetName(0) + ',' + reader.GetName(1));

            while (reader.Read())
                file.WriteLine(reader[0].ToString() + ',' + reader[1].ToString());
               }

        conn.Close();
    }

}
catch (Exception e) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(8000);
}
```

Comment: Hi, yes but I don't know for to add the Console.ReadLine() witht the values inside the call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question below is the code for you.

```
    //Adding values to the stored procedure
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter project title and press Enter");

                string projectTitle = Console.ReadLine();
                while (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(projectTitle))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter project title and press Enter");
                    projectTitle = Console.ReadLine();
                }


                string outCsvFile = string.Format(@"D:\\test\\{0}.csv", projectTitle);
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(outCsvFile))
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException("File already exist Name " + outCsvFile);
                }
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectTitle", projectTitle); //this value I would like to add it when the console application is executed when I will hit on enter.
```

Comment: Hi your solution worked perfect but the problem is that the output file have the test.csv what its inside the string outCsvFile. There's a way to add the name of the file as the projectTitle given into the console?, Thanks again

Comment: Perfect I just tried it and it word. I am sorry but one last thing. I noticed that if in the console nothing is entered as a project name (just hit enter) its display the error message but if I want put it in way to give the message until its enter a project name, what its the best way to proceed? thanks again

Comment: update the answer with while condition instead of If

Comment: I just tried and it worked. You're the best!!!! thanks a lot for all the patience and time!!!

Comment: Sorry I don't know if its too late to ask you the following. I would like to ask the user as much times he would like to enter a project name until he click in the X to close the windows without finishing the app. Its is possible? thanks again

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways that I know a console application can get input. One is from the ReadLine or ReadKey method. The other is from the command line argument. If you run your executable in command prompt and supply some values, you can get it in your console app.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleParameter
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // get from the command line parameter
            Console.WriteLine("Parameter in command line");
            foreach (var arg in args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(arg);
            }

            // get from keyboard input when the console is running
            Console.WriteLine("Please input something");
            var value = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("You entered {0}", value);

            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshot of running the console in command prompt.
[image]

You can also provide the command line arguments in Visual Studio, so you can test it without running it from the command prompt.[image]

Answer (score 0):

The values will be in order.

```
var someEnteredValue = Console.ReadLine();
```

//Hit enter and then:

```
var nextEnteredValue = Console.ReadLine();
```