# Feed Input argument before starting the Program

Tags: c#, datetime

I am making a program, a tiny piece of code where I want to get the Week Number when you enter the date. But there is a small twist, I don't want to feed the argument after running the program but before it. I want to start my program from `Run` or `Ctrl + R`. My program is called `getWeek`. So when I type in the Run `getWeek 6-11-2015`  I should get a TextBox saying "Week 45". Its purely hobby work. Below is my code to find week number.

```
public static int GetIso8601WeekOfYear(DateTime time)
{
    DayOfWeek day = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetDayOfWeek(time);
    if (day >= DayOfWeek.Monday && day <= DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
    {
        time = time.AddDays(3);
    }
    return CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(time, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);
}
```

The issue is how to get `DateTime time` from Run. Please help.

Comment: Is it a console application?

Comment: If it's a console application, you can supply arguments when you call it. See my answer in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816049/calling-stored-procedure-values-into-the-console-application-c-sharp/31816326#31816326).

Comment: It is a form Application.

Comment: How exactly would you enter something into a forms application before starting it? Can you be more specific about what behaviour you seek?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide some arguments when you call your app. Just modify the Main method in Program.cs. Add an array in your Main method. Then you can run the exe and add some values behind the exe, eg `WindowsApplication6 abc def ghi`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication6
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (var arg in args)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(arg);
            }

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to supply some parameters from Visual Studio (like when you are debugging), you can add them in the project properties.

[image]

Comment: This is I was looking for. @handodko Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is, that you can't convert your input `string` into `DateTime`.
Here is a method, which you can use to get the `DateTime`:

```
    public static DateTime GetDateTimeFromString(string date)
    {
        string[] split = date.Split('-');
        int day = Convert.ToInt32(split[0]);
        int month = Convert.ToInt32(split[1]);
        int year = Convert.ToInt32(split[2]);
        return new DateTime(year, month, day);
    }
```

**NOTE**: This function is specific for your formatted string.

Then you can call this method like this:

```
        string date = "06-11-2015";
        DateTime time = GetDateTimeFromString(date);
        textBox1.Text = "Week " + Convert.ToString(GetIso8601WeekOfYear(time));
```